# How can i filter data from array with more words in input?

Tags: angular

i'm still learning angular and i want to make a search bar or filter to filter my fetched data from database, but i don't know how. My data looks like this:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0do9J.png)

I want to filter data with name and surname together. So when i type "John John" into my input field it will return me this array where the name and surname is John John. Filters i tried only filters by only name or only surname so when i typed John it returns me that array but when i typed John John it returns me nothing.

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have plenty of options depending on how "fuzzy" you want the search to be.
E.g. if you type "John John" shall user `{name: "John", surname: "Doe"}` be in the results or must `name` & `surname` be matched?

A very basic approach would be to check if either the *name* or *surname* is part of the search-string. This could be done by [`filtering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array via [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

(See full example on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=51&pln=17&pc=142#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXDA3mBBbApm6AJwEswBzAGhggFdCs8CoTyBfAbQF0YBeGd9ACgYImA3wwARACkQACzCSKw0bXo4JM+YsGsqQ0WI1otCpSpFrxJgCIhck3fotHGUgAq4ouQucNXjKVkzJwwXaw8vHz9VOgjJdwRCAGto3U5BQVBIWAhcJOA5RMIcJhYyXiDtGGCdLPBoGEJcWgAbKDRMQKJSSmo47uZejm4+RGQAOgAzYnafAAoaPMJeAD5qfMJC4pwJ0mBWmjgWxeWJ8QBKGAAfa42CoqTd-cPjiFOfCYC8C4uAbky2QgIFauAmrRAZHmzTaUH+QA))

```
data.filter(user => searchParam.includes(user.name) || searchParam.includes(user.surname));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but, how can i implement it to html to show me only data that matches the name or surname ? I have *ngFor in a div element that shows me all the data but i don't know how to show data with that name or surname

Comment: Just store the filtered result in a variable and use e.g. angulars [text interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation) to display it. Check out this basic example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-21tytf?file=src/app/app.component.html).
Additionally, I recommend you doing the ["Tour of Heroes" Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) which will introduce you to the basic concepts of angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function of javascript

```
function filterData(dataList: any[], name: string, surname: string) {
  
  return dataList.filter( (dataObj) => ( dataObj.name == name && dataObj.surname == surname))

}
```

Something like this?

**EDITED**

Sorry I used ts but is the same

```
function filterData(dataList, name, surname) {
  
  return dataList.filter( (dataObj) => ( dataObj.name == name && dataObj.surname == surname))

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and i want to ask how can i implement this function into my html ?

Comment: If you are using Angular you can use the ***ngFor** directive for to show a list of Data formatted as you want https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/

Comment: Yes i know, but i meant how can i pass that function into html to work with my data

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(key: string): Data[]{
    if(key){
        return this.data.filter(x=>`${x.name} ${x.surname}`.toLowerCase().match(key.toLowerCase()));
    }
    return this.data;
}
```

Maybe this can help.